# Image Array and Arrow Keys

Tags: javascript, arrays, image

I'm just trying to get a hang of javascript, and this is a script I assembled from various sources, just simple enough so I can understand on the level it is. Please don't get too complex, though if you do I would appreciate small explanation and don't expect me to know...

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">
imgs=Array("01.jpg","02.jpg","03.jpg","04.jpg","05.jpg");
var x=0;
document.onkeydown = checkKey;
function checkKey(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    if (e.keyCode == '37') {
        document.getElementById("myImage").src=imgs[--x];
    }
    else if (e.keyCode == '39') {
        document.getElementById("myImage").src=imgs[++x];
    }
}
</script>
```

and in the body...

```
<img id="myImage" src="01.jpg" style="width:100%">
```

What it's supposed to do is make a simple image gallery of images that fit to the screen width, which can be navigated from the images in the array using arrow keys. It works fine, for me at least, except the fact that if I try to go to the previous image while x=0, or the next image from x=4, it extends indefinitely, not looping back to 01.jpg from 05.jpg and vice versa as I want. My theory didn't work. I just know bits and pieces about this. Anybody know an easy way to with the least modification to this original script?

It doesn't have to look professional or 'pretty'. I'm just bored, and experimenting around. Maybe future aspirations to be a web designer, but not for now certainly :D Oh, and please no JQuery referencing? Sure they work, but I just want to understand a solution to this on a basic level, and get a standalone script.

Comment: The `--x` and `++x` decrement and increment will never stop in either direction, if you wish them to wrap then use a modulo when you change them.  A modulo is the remainder of a division.  If you divide by the total elements in the array and take the remainder, it will keep you within bounds. `x = ((x-1) + imgs.length) % imgs.length` or `x = (x+1) % imgs.length`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this should do the trick:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">
imgs=Array("01.jpg","02.jpg","03.jpg","04.jpg","05.jpg");
var number_of_images = imgs.length
var x=0;
document.onkeydown = checkKey;
function checkKey(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    if (e.keyCode == '37') {
        if (x == 0) 
            x = number_of_images - 1;
        else
            x--;
    }
    else if (e.keyCode == '39') {
        if (x == (number_of_images - 1))
            x = 0;
        else
            x++;
    }
    document.getElementById("myImage").src=imgs[x];
}
</script>
```

Comment: Changed var number_of_images to var y just for simplicity's sake, but yeah, it works. Thanks :D

Comment: Simplicity will ruin your code. Given that you're just getting the hang of it, also the get the hang of properly naming your variables, functions etc. Don't be like: "this is just so I can learn what this does". Take a few milliseconds to give meaningful names to stuff. You'll appreciate it later :P

Comment: Maybe later. Sure, I get what you're trying to mean, that IF I ever make a big project I'd be confused with a large number of nonsensical variables labeled 'y', 'z', 's' and stuff if I make this a habit, a habit as bad as inline js maybe? Thanks for the warning; so how does 'imgTotal' sound? Oh, and if you've got the time, could you please explain the 'e = e || window.event'? My script works without that... I didn't quite get that part ehehe :'D

Comment: That `e = e || window.event` is for browser compatibility. On some (most), the event is passed as a parameter to the callback, on others (IE I think) the event is a global state placed on the window object.

Answer (score 0):

Check if `x == 0` or `x == imgs.length - 1` in your code and adjust accordingly:

```
function checkKey(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    if (e.keyCode == '37') {
        if (x == 0) x = imgs.length
        document.getElementById("myImage").src=imgs[--x];
    }
    else if (e.keyCode == '39') {
        if (x == imgs.length - 1) x = -1
        document.getElementById("myImage").src=imgs[++x];
    }
}
```

So decrementing (`x--`) in the first case will put you at the last index, and incrementing (`++x`) in the second case will put you at `0`, aka the first index.

Comment: can it be done like this?
var y=imgs.length
function checkKey(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    if (e.keyCode == '37') {
        if (x == 0) x = y
        document.getElementById("myImage").src=imgs[--x];
    }
    else if (e.keyCode == '39') {
        if (x == y - 1) x = -1
        document.getElementById("myImage").src=imgs[++x];
    }
}

Comment: So you're just replacing `imgs.length` with `y`? Yes you can do that. In fact, that's recommended over my result, since you only have to call that operation once instead of every time.

Comment: hmm... that's appreciated. But what exactly did you mean by 'check for in your code'?

Comment: Just check if `x` meets either of those conditions, using `if` statements.

Comment: 'kay, got it. Could you please explain the 'e = e || window.event'? My script works without that... is it a useless line for some reason? I didn't quite get that part ehehe :'D

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">
imgs=Array("01.jpg","02.jpg","03.jpg","04.jpg","05.jpg");
console.log(imgs.length);
var x=0;
document.onkeydown = checkKey;
function checkKey(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    if (e.keyCode == '37') {        
        x--;
        if(x == -1){ x = imgs.length - 1; console.log('a max'); }
        //document.getElementById("myImage").src=imgs[x];
        console.log('a '+x);

    }
    else if (e.keyCode == '39') {       
        x++;
        if(x == imgs.length){ x = 0; console.log('b max'); }
        //document.getElementById("myImage").src=imgs[x];
        console.log('b '+x);     
    }
}
</script>
```

**SAME THING ONLY SMALLER (1 line)**

```
 i=Array("01.jpg","02.jpg","03.jpg","04.jpg","05.jpg");var x=0;document.onkeydown=checkKey;function checkKey(e){e=e||window.event;if(e.keyCode=='37'){x--;if(x==-1){x=i.length-1;}document.getElementById("myImage").src=i[x];}else if(e.keyCode=='39'){x++;if(x==i.length){x=0;}document.getElementById("myImage").src=i[x];}}
```

Comment: I'm sure it works, but can this be... scaled down in size or something? :D But thanks anyway.